# 2008 vti refuses to start.what should I do?

Tags: engine, honda, civic

I have a 2008 vti and it refuses to start. The engine only makes "tch" sound everytime the key is turned on. I have tried moving it in reverse and forward as some make-shift mechanics suggested (reason to do is, at times the gear is not in the proper idle condition). Apart from all this got the air filter removed to access the starter terminals and found them to be corroded. What do you suggest, that i get it cleaned or replace it? And what if that is not the case? Like, is there any other reason for the car not starting any fuse or relay?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here.

First, get the terminals cleaned at both the battery and the starter. You want these connections to be able to make good connections.

Second, usually when you hear the sound you are describing, the battery is low, so may need replacement. Since you have corroded connections, it may still be low, but be rechargeable. If once you get the terminals cleaned up, see if it will start the car. If it doesn't, put a battery charger on the battery and see if it will come up to snuff (fully charged it should be ~13.1vdc with the engine off). If it will only charge to say 11.9vdc, you'll probably want to look at buying a battery soon. If it's below 10vdc, it definitely needs replacing.

You definitely have to clean the terminals. This may keep electricity flowing (for both starting and charging) and may be the root cause. If this doesn't fix things, it could be the battery, but the battery *may just* need recharged at this point.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but that was not the case.the battery, its terminals, relays, and all the wiring were all in their perfect condition the life of the starter solenoid was over. The starting solenoid doesn't give any exciting current to the dynamo for creating the required charge for triggering the start-up.So when it was replaced the car is as its new.